# Closed points in the finite point exclusion topology and the general notion of open sets?

Tags: general-topology

I'm struggling with grasping the notion of open sets as they apply to topological spaces. For example, if we consider the finite point exclusion topology, $T$, defined by $$T = \{ A \subseteq X \mid p \notin A \ \text{or} \ A = X\}$$any singleton set of the form $\{x \mid x\in X\}$ belongs in $T$, so it is *open*. However, this set is obviously closed in $X$. How does one distinguish?

What got me thinking about this was a problem that asked what the closed sets in the exclude point topology are. Clearly all singleton sets and their finite unions, including $X$ itself, are closed sets in $T$. But those sets are also open? I don't understand.

Comment: In a general topological space sets may be open and closed. This does not correspond to our intuitive understanding of open and closed.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I apologize if my questions seem rather simple, as I've just started learning the subject. Does this mean that a set can be closed in $X$ while still being "open" in a topology on $T$?

Comment: @CodyButler No.It is more basic than that. A set can be both closed and open with respect to the same topology. And you might want to edit your post: what you defined as $A$ is actually $T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A set $A$ is open in $T$ so long as $A \in T$, correct?

Comment: @CodyButler No. If $(X,T)$ is a topological space (where $X$ is a set and $T\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a topology) and if $A\subset X$, then the assertion $A$ is open means that $A\in T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think I understand. A set $A \subset (X,T)$ is open implies $A\in T$?

Comment: @CodyButler No. A set $A\subset X$ being open is *equivalent* (by definition) to $A\in T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, I see. So in the example in the OP, any singleton set $\{x\}$, so long as $x$ is not the excluded point, is both open (because $\{x\} \in T$) and closed?

Comment: @CodyButler That's right!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it's going to take some getting used to, but thank you.

Comment: If $p\in X$ and $X\ne\{p\}$  then it is not true that $\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in X,$ as  $\{p\}$  will not be open.

Comment: The set $\{x\mid x\in X\}$ is the same as the set $X.$ Just what you intended that notation to mean may be unclear. Might you have meant $\{x\}$ for $x\in X\text{?}$ That at least would be a singleton. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a set can be both open and closed. In any topology on $X$ there are at least two examples of such sets, that is $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself. If there are more subsets of the topological space $(X,T)$ that are both open and closed, we say that the topological space $(X,T)$ is disconnected.

But this isn't the case in your question. Note that for the topology $T = \{A \subset X \mid p \not \in A \text{ or } A =X\}$, a subset $A \subset X$ is open if and only if $A$ doesn't contain $p$ or is equal to $X$. A set $B \subset X$ is closed if and only if $B^c$ is open. So $B$ is closed if and only if it contains $p$ or is equal to the empty set. Thus the only sets that are both open and closed are the empty set and $X$ itself.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition from the topology of $\Bbb R^n$ and metric spaces doesn't always transfer that well to general topological spaces, which can be quite strange. For example, in an arbitrary topological space, singletons need not be closed. (FYI, a space where every singleton set is closed is called a [$T_1$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space), and there are certainly [examples of non-$T_1$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#Spaces_which_are_T0_but_not_T1).)

Let's look at your example. Recall that by definition, a subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,T)$ is open if $A\in T$. The notion of closed-ness is also completely dependent on $T$: a subset $A$ is closed in $(X,T)$ if its complement is open (that is, $X\setminus A\in T$). Say $x\in X$. If $x\neq p$, the set $\{x\}$ is open: $p\not\in\{x\}$. In this case, $\{x\}$ is *not* closed: $p\not\in\{x\}$, which implies that $p\in X\setminus\{x\}$, so $X\setminus\{x\}\not\in T$. If $x = p$, $\{p\}$ is closed: $p\in\{p\}$, so that $p\not\in X\setminus\{p\}$, which means $X\setminus\{p\}$ is open. We also see that $\{p\}$ is not open, unless $X = \{p\}$: $p\in\{p\}$, so $\{p\}\not\in T$ unless $\{p\} = X$.

One can also find examples of topologies where singletons may be both open and closed (like the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) on a space), either open or closed (like your example), or neither open nor closed (the [generic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point) is neither open nor closed in the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology#Examples) on $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Very detailed and clear. Thank you